# Extract lines from a file based on a separate CSV

Tags: shell-script, text-formatting

I have two files, `var.txt` and `res.dat`.

#### Example `var.txt`

```
date,request,sales,item
20171015,1,123456,216
20171015,1,123456,217
20171015,2,123456,214
20171015,2,345678,213
20171015,2,345678,214
20171015,3,456789,218
20171015,3,345678,217
20171015,4,567890,212
```

#### Example `res.dat`

```
RTCCVB01                213456                   123456                216
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   345678                214
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   123456                214
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   345678                213
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   123456                217
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   345678                217
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   456789                218
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   567890                212
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

---

For a given request number (the second field in `var.txt`), I need to find the corresponding `RTCCVB01` line in `res.dat` by matching the sales number (the third column, position 50-56) and item number (fourth column, position 72-79), and extract all lines from there to `VBPCVB01`.

For example, if the request number is `1`, the following lines in `var.txt` apply:

```
20171015,1,123456,216
20171015,1,123456,217
```

So I need the entries from `res.dat` with sales number `123456` and item number `216` or `217`:

```
RTCCVB01                213456                   123456                216
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   123456                217
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

For request 2 it would be:

```
RTCCVB01                213456                   123456                214
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   345678                213
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   345678                214
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

Request 3:

```
RTCCVB01                213456                   456789                218
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
RTCCVB01                213456                   345678                217
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

Request 4:

```
RTCCVB01                213456                   567890                212
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

---

I need each of the results stored in a separate file; in this case, `1.dat` through `4.dat`. How do I go about writing a shell script that will process the entire `var.txt`, extracting rows from `res.dat` and creating dat files for each unique request number?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. I'm also not seeing a code or script issue. It even sounds like you are asking us to do the work for you. It might help if you could post the code you have tried so far. This will help a lot.

Comment: @Tigger i am new to shell script . i am able to split the res.dat file without any conditions but i am unable to take information from var.txt and correspondingly extract information from res.dat and create a new dat file.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a script to parse res.dat and write each section, from the sales+item-combination in var.txt to the closing `VBPCVB01` in the file for the given request. This script would be like `script.sh`:

```
sed "
/RTCCVB01.*123456.*216/,/VBPCVB01/w 1.dat
/RTCCVB01.*123456.*217/,/VBPCVB01/w 1.dat
/RTCCVB01.*123456.*214/,/VBPCVB01/w 2.dat
/RTCCVB01.*345678.*213/,/VBPCVB01/w 2.dat
/RTCCVB01.*345678.*214/,/VBPCVB01/w 2.dat
/RTCCVB01.*456789.*218/,/VBPCVB01/w 3.dat
/RTCCVB01.*345678.*217/,/VBPCVB01/w 3.dat
/RTCCVB01.*567890.*212/,/VBPCVB01/w 4.dat
d;" res.dat
```

I did not write this script myself, but I let `sed` write it:

```
sed -E 's/date.*/sed "/;s_.*,(.*),(.*),(.*)_/RTCCVB01.*\2.*\3/,/VBPCVB01/w \1.dat_;${h;s/.*/d;" res.dat/;x;G}' var.txt > script.sh
```

This `sed` script writes the script `script.sh`, which you can call by

```
/bin/sh script.sh
```

and should do

Comment: different dat files needs to be created based on second column in var.txt request . In var.txt , total number of unique request is 3(1,2,3) , so 3 dat files will be created which will based on sales(3rd column (sales)in var.txt and 4th column(item) in var.txt )

Comment: i also need to check correspondingly the 4th column item from var.txt along with 3rd column item and take both as input and  extract information from res.dat and create a separate dat file.For each request in var.txt file , it will create one dat file.

res.dat file contains sales at 50th position same as 3rd column in var.txt and ITEM at 119 postion same as 4th column

i have to recursively seach by taking input SALES,ITEM from var.txt and extract information from res.dat and create dat files correspondinly for each request

Comment: You don't need the 4th column as all requests in `res.dat` with a 4th column match also match in the 3rd column. So the script already gives the output you requested. Or in how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: if the var.txt contains one more item                                                              date,request,sales,item
20171015,4,123456,213 then in this case it should create another dat file

Comment: i want to take inputs sales and items from var.txt and it should create one dat file by extracting information from res.dat per each request as  in var.txt

Comment: kindly explain how the below will work                                    
    sed -E 's/date./sed "/;s_.,(.),(.),(.)_/RTCCVB01.\2.\3/,/VBPCVB01/w \1.dat_;${h;s/./d;" res.dat/;x;G}'

Comment: One <space> was missing for correct indenting, so the code got messed up. I corrected it.

Comment: kindly explain how you determine this regular expression 's/date.*/sed "/;s_.*,(.*),(.*),(.*)_/RTCCVB01.*\2.*\3/,/VBPCVB01/w \1.dat_;${h;s/.*/d;" res.dat/;x;G} to achieve the desired result

Comment: That script output another script. I redirect the output of that script to a file, which I do execute then.

Comment: i need a single script which i will schedule in crontab in daily basis

Comment: It's no problem for a cron job. The cron job script creates the other script and executes it. Very simple.

Comment: Thanks . Kindly help in understanding the following line       
   sed -E 's/date.*/sed "/;s_.*,(.*),(.*),(.*)_/RTCCVB01.*\2.*\3/,/VBPCVB01/w \1.dat_;${h;s/.*/d;" res.dat/;x;G}' var.txt.